# Tensorflow weights that act as linear scaling

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network

I have a neural network with output neurons I want to scale linearly with trained weights before soft maxing.

I have 10 outputs, I want 10 weights which are multiplied by each of the outputs before the output is soft maxed. So 1 weight per output.

But I keep getting the error `Shape must be rank 2 but is rank 1 for 'MatMul_2` and it tells me my shapes are `[?,10], [10]`

Before my code was

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 784])
W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([784, 10]))
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10]))
y = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(x, W) + b)
```

Now it is this

```
x_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 784])
W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([784, 10]))
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10]))
W_pre_final = tf.Variable(tf.ones([10]))
y_pre_final = tf.matmul(x_, W) + b
y = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(y_pre_final, W_pre_final))
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 10])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for element-wise multiplication, not matrix multiplication

```
tf.multiply(y_pre_final, tf.expand_dims(W_pre_final,0))
```